# Como ler corretamente uma documentação de um comando SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, documentação, microsoft

Estava estudando o conceito de transações e como sempre a referência foi a documentação da própria Microsoft (no caso para os produtos da mesma).

No link abaixo há a documentação do comando BEGIN TRANSACTION.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

A primeira linha do bloco sintaxe é: 
BEGIN { TRAN | TRANSACTION }

O uso de chaves “{}” representa o que?
O uso de pipe “|” representa que eu posso optar em utilizar o comando TRAN ou TRANSACTION?
O uso de colchetes “[]” representa comando opcionais?

Comment: O uso de chaves é um agrupador de um campo obrigatório e serve para indicar as opções disponíveis. Nesse caso tem TRAN e TRANSACTION divididas por pipe, o que indica que pode usar a abreviação ou o nome completo. o uso de colchetes indica algo opcional.

Comment: A origem da notação está na BNF ou Backus-Naur Form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A notação para documentação significa o seguinte:

`{ }` ou `< >`:  o que está dentro de chaves é **obrigatório**, deve ser usado

`{ x | y }` ou `< x | y >`: deve ser escolhida uma opção, x ou y, é **obrigatório**

`[  ]`: o que está dentro dos colchetes é **opcional**, pode ser usando ou não

Aqui mais detalhes sobre a notação usada na sintaxe: [Sintax notation](https://docs.informatica.com/data-quality-and-governance/data-quality/10-2-hotfix-2/command-reference/using-the-command-line-programs/syntax-notation.html)

Analisando seu exemplo:

```
1 BEGIN { TRAN | TRANSACTION }   
2     [ { transaction_name | @tran_name_variable }  
3       [ WITH MARK [ 'description' ] ]  
4     ]  
5 [ ; ]
```

1. O comando começa com `BEGIN` e deve **obrigatoriamente** ser seguido por uma das opções ou `TRAN` (versão resumida) ou `TRANSACTION`
2. O `[` indica que é **opcional** declarar ou não variáveis
3. É **opcional** declarar ou não `WITH MARK` e ainda é **opcional** a descrição
4. Esse colchete encerra o que foi aberto na linha 2
5. É **opcional** encerrar com o `;`

Outro exemplo é o [Comando SELECT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]   
    [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ]   
    < select_list >   
    [ INTO new_table ]   
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ]   
    [ <GROUP BY> ]   
    [ HAVING < search_condition > ]
```

Veja que no comando `SELECT`,  usar `ALL` ou `DISTINCT` é opcional, assim como `INTO` e `WHERE` por exemplo, mas o `< select_list >` é obrigatório, ou seja, a lista de campos, variáveis ou valores do comando `SELECT`

Um simples `SELECT 1` então funciona, baseado na descrição da sintaxe acima :)

Comment: Agradeço! Ficava confuso e acaba optando por fontes não oficiais! Tks!

Answer (score 5):

As chaves são uma forma de agrupamento, significa que tudo que está ali dentro é uma coisa só, é como se fosse parênteses em uma expressão de programação normal que elimina a ambiguidade. Então obviamente dentro tem mais de um elemento, afinal não teria porque agrupar só uma coisa. Neste caso tem algo que deve escolher por isso tem o `|` (é um OU), portanto é uma coisa ou outra, e neste caso específico ele permite a forma completa da palavra ou a forma abreviada.

Os colchetes de fato indica que algo é opcional e se não usar não afeta a sintaxe, pode afetar a semântica em boa parte dos casos, mas em SQL tem muito caso que é só simplificação de sintaxe, o mesmo ali em cima poderia ser documentado assim:

```
BEGIN TRAN[SACTION]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Other/BeginTrans.sql).

Mas não é comum fazer assim, fica um pouco menos claro.

Comment: Se a pessoa que negativou puder indicar o que tem de errado na resposta eu posso consertar, mas aparentemente não tem nada porque o que está escrito aqui é o mesmo da outra resposta que não recebeu negativo.